Short story where a goddess promises a priestess she will see the future, but the way she held her promise was not what was expected
I'm looking for a rather short fiction which I read at least 30 years ago, probably from some collection. I only very rarely read magazines. I think it was a rather big volume, more of an anthology than an "ordinary" collection.
I read it in English. As far as I can remember it was not a special dialect, nor slang. Also, I am not really fluent enough to tell UK from US English, so I cannot give this indication on the author.
A priestess is praying to her goddess as their city is being invaded by barbarians and she fears that she will be soon dead. But I don't remember any explicit violence/sex/gore. The goddess answers her prayer by a promise that she will see the future. One does not see the priestess die in the story.
In a museum, a lady archeologist is staying late at night putting order to objects recently acquired. A crown (we understand that it belonged to the priestess) is attracting her and on an impulse she puts it on her head. Immediately she is feeling as if inhabited by another person. She goes to the gate of the museum and looks outside. She sees the buildings, cars running in the streets. Through her eyes the priestess sees the future. The goddess has kept her promise...

Your title wasn't clear enough so I changed it. Also, a recommendation: make it clearer what is the actual question... I guess you want to know which short story is this, or the collection to which it belongs?

@AndresF. The short story itself, yes.

your edit to the title made it seem as if you're asking whether the priestess fulfilled her promise. Since what you're actually asking for is the title of the story, I rolled back your edit.

I've been there before. We have a list at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines of outstanding bounties for which we don't want to spend rep when there's no likely answer. Admittedly, it's been a while since the last update, but it's probably still fine to edit yours in.

@FuzzyBoots I am not sure this meta post  has more visibility than this edited post, but I did do what was suggested there.

This edit...  I don't feel it's consistent with the point of a question; I'm tempted to roll it back, honestly.

@DavidW What is the point of a bounty if noone visits the question ? FuszzyBoots  meta page is a good idea, I did post my question on it, but again, how many people check that meta page ? Anyway, if you roll back the titel, please leave my edit on top of the question, don't roll it back at the bottom

@DavidW - I Agree. OP has added a comment into the body of the question. I've removed it.

Rather than posting additional words about your fabulous bounty, perhaps you might like to have a read through the suggestions here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. Giving us more details will help us to find your answer

@Valorum I'd love to add any relevant info. I just put everything I remember. My point is, very few people have visited this post. This is why I wanted to change the title. Some of my answered aquesion kept getting visited long after being answered and up to thousands of visits. This one has just a few hundreds. I'd like to have more people reading it. Any details I could remember  I already gave.

@Alfred - I'd be willing to bet that there's info you recall but that you've not put in your question. For example, what language did you read it in? Was there explicit sex/gore/violence? Was it written in a particular dialect? Which goddess? Which city? Who were the invaders? Why were they invading? Does the goddess speak to her in her mind or appear in person? Does the priestess die during the story or does it happen off-screen? Where are you likely to have read it (for example, have you ever subscribed to a scifi magazine)?

@Valorum BTW, thank you for your bounty. I just saw it, after my previous comment. One more bounty will indeed bring more visits. But I'd have to put at least 300 for just one week.  It's not worht it. In any case I will create the 500 bounty for the correct answer, but only after I have ascertained it is the one.

@Valorum Re your comment on more details. I read it in English, but I don't remember any special dialect. I cannot even tell if is was rather UK or US. I'm not fluent enough for that. I'll really try to remember any details according to your suggestions

At first I thought this might be Philip Dick's "The Eye of the Sybil", which does feature a sybil who somehow sees the future, but upon review that short story is way more autobiographical than I remembered! Sorry, your story is not entirely unfamiliar but I cannot put my finger on a title...

@AndresF. I found a synopsis of "The Eye of the Sybil". Definitely not my story.

@Alfred I undid your edit that added a link to a metadiscussion for lists of bounties. That's unrelated to this question and shouldn't exist in the main body of the question. Your meta-comment stands on its own.
